# How to close a browser window after an exit event trigger in a unity webgl game (for accessibility sake)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, browser, accessibility, exit, unity-webgl

I have to develop a browser based game with WebGL (for cross-platform support) using Unity that allows people with severe disabilities to take full control of their experience. This also includes opening and closing the application on their own. Opening the browser and game is pretty straightforward since these people can simply open them using a program provided by another company (like Tobii), but now I am facing an issue when trying to close the window again, since there doesn't seem to be a way to achieve this from within the browser/game.

My question is, is there a way to close the browser with JavaScript or maybe even in Unity itself? Or should I look towards creating an application outside of the browser with something like Java (for cross-platform support) that manages the browser window?

I already looked into ways of doing it via JavaScript or even from within unity, but I simply couldn't find a solution. I tried using JavaScript's `windows.close()` function, but that only works on windows opened from within JavaScript itself by the looks of it. Looking at a stand-alone application then leaves the question of how to detect an exit request from the user when they are done playing the game.

What I am looking for is a way for them to select an 'exit' button within the game which then closes the browser, so they can return to their assistance program, without the help from another person. 
Currently, the user is only able to make use of a single button and can't control mouse or cursor themselves, meaning that they can't close the browser on their own.

**tl;dr how can I close a browser window using an exit button in a WebGL Unity game for a person who isn't able to themselves due to a handicap?**

Answer (score 2):

## Pretty sure you can't

And that goes back to `window.close` only working on windows opened with JS. Originally it *could* close any window, but people started abusing that fact (think about things like the self-retweeting tweet, except it also closes your browser tab!)

So the restriction got added.

This is why we can't have nice things.

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much already, so I guess those are the limits using JS. Can you think of any alternatives that might be worth looking into? Like for example using a manager application (if that sort of thing is possible) that looks out for a certain action happening in a browser? I realize this is a pretty ambiguous questions, but it's a pretty big bottleneck at the moment and any recommendation helps. Thanks either way!

Comment: Again, it would only work if your game wi dow was opened by JS in the first place.